# how to get Custom List Item Property

Tags: 2007, list, development, properties

I added a new column to Sharepoint Custom list which is boolean type, now each time I upload a item to list, it displays that column to check or leave it blank, by default its checked, I wanna access this property programmatically but can't remember how to do it.

```
public void Documents(string URL)
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(URL))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Mes"];

        if (list.ItemCount != 0)
        {
            foreach (SPListItem listItem in list.Items)
            {
                if(listItem.)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited**

I guess using this statement

```
listItem.Properties["columnName"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's actually:

```
listitem["columnname"]
```

in SharePoint 2007/WSS 3.0

Comment: the one I added does work as well :)

Comment: I meant to say "as well as". Thanks!